# Change the value of a button from true to another value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `ng-repeat` where the most of the data I am displaying is text, but when the DB sends data starting with `XX`, I should represent it as button.

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in rows">
  <td ng-repeat="column in cols" ng-init="isXX = column.indexOf('XX') === 0">
     <span ng-if="!isXX">{{row[column]}}</span>
     <button ng-if="isXX">{{row[column]}}</button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

in this case, the values with `XX` are something like this

`XX_FILL_OPEN: true` so this `<button ng-if="isXX">{{row[column]}}</button>`

has a value `true` like in the image

[image]

this is what I have in the controller

```
    ReportsFactory.pendingBets(reportParam).then(function(data) {
      gridInfo = _.forEach(data, function(item) {return item;});
      $scope.rows = gridInfo;
      $scope.cols = Object.keys($scope.rows[0]);
    }
```

so, all I want is change that `true` value in the button and puth `Fill Open` instead.

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
<button ng-if="isXX">{{row[column]}}</button>
```

with

```
<button ng-if="isXX">{{column.substring(3).replace('_', ' ').toLowerCase()}}</button>
```

This should take the column value 'XX_FILL_OPEN' and

- remove the first 3 characters leaving 'FILL_OPEN'
- replace '_' with ' ' leaving 'FILL OPEN'
- change casing to lower case leaving 'fill open'

Comment: Thank you. If this worked for you, please accept the answer.